# dealing with case sensitivity in client side xslt accross ie6+ and mozilla

Tags: xml, case-sensitive

I am delivering a small amount of XML to the client wrapped in a DIV, using jQuery I snip it out, store it as a string (called text) and convert it into a XMLdoc fragment.

In IE(6+) I use:

```
var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
doc.async='false';
doc.loadXML(text);
```

in MOZILLA(3+) I use:

```
var parser=new DOMParser();
var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
```

this works fine, except that IE capitalises all the tag names, and Mozilla puts them all into lower case. The problem is that the XSLT I am then applying to them is case sensitive, and I am therefore having to write 2 templates, eg:

```
<xsl:template match="VIDEOPLAYER">...
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="videoplayer">...
```

which are doing the same thing (in this case injecting javascript).

(I do not want to do the XSLT on the server because I don't want to have to parse every outgoing page, and that would be a problem for our server.)

So does anyone know if there is either a way to control the case transformations that happens in the creation of the XML object, or a way of dealing with case in my XSLT xpath match attributes.

Comment: There shouldn't be any case conversions done when parsing XML, only when parsing HTML. How exactly is the XML "wrapped in the div"? Generally using unescaped XML "islands" within an HTML doc isn't going to work well; if you're going to hold XML within HTML it's probably best to escape it or put it in script elements.

Comment: it's wrapped in a div in the sense that there is a div element with a specific ID around it. It is not unescaped - it has it's own namespace, in exactly the same way that including SVG or MathML is included in a HTML file, except it has it's own DTD, it's meant to be a DSL that describes various complex UI elements that get converted client side. My best info. so far is that browsers are unreliable.

Comment: Yes, wrapping XML in HTML this way is indeed unreliable. Sadly so. I'm afraid some of the browser vendors are less than enthusastic about XML - perhaps they see it as a threat. I would keep the XML in a separate document, fetched separately from the server. Take a look at how you might do this in Saxon-CE.

Comment: Thanks, sadly this was a workaround for a bug in our (expensive!) cms that means I can't put script tags inside any templates that are nested - which is what I need to allow our editors to 'drop-in' widgets into general content (long story....), currently I'm using PHP but I was trying to push it onto the client - I will try to think about how to serve it as separate XML, I suspect the CMS isn't going to publish 2 documents under these circumstances, maybe JSON wrapped in a CDATA... Anyway I am rambling now, grateful for your input.